# What are the correct units when dealing with CameraPostion, CameraPostion.Builder?

Tags: mapbox

From the docs it seems that `CameraPosition` should be using degrees for its bearing member. Its builder class however converts degrees passed in to radians.

```
/**
 * Sets the direction that the camera is pointing in, in degrees clockwise from north.
 *
 * @param bearing Bearing
 * @return Builder
 */
public Builder bearing(double bearing) {
    if (isRadiant) {
        this.bearing = bearing;
    } else {
        // converting degrees to radiant
        this.bearing = (float) (-bearing * MathConstants.DEG2RAD);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Here is CameraPosition's constructor. It would seem that the builder should keep the bearing in degrees or convert to degrees if its in radians since the constructor is expecting degrees.

```
/**
 * Constructs a CameraPosition.
 *
 * @param target  The target location to align with the center of the screen.
 * @param zoom    Zoom level at target. See zoom(float) for details of restrictions.
 * @param tilt    The camera angle, in degrees, from the nadir (directly down). See tilt(float) for details of restrictions.
 * @param bearing Direction that the camera is pointing in, in degrees clockwise from north. This value will be normalized to be within 0 degrees inclusive and 360 degrees exclusive.
 * @throws NullPointerException     if target is null
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if tilt is outside the range of 0 to 90 degrees inclusive.
 */
CameraPosition(LatLng target, double zoom, double tilt, double bearing) {
    this.target = target;
    this.bearing = bearing;
    this.tilt = tilt;
    this.zoom = zoom;
```

Answer (score 2):

The default units are `degrees`.

As you mentioned, the builder converts degrees to radians.  This holds unless the Builder uses `isRadiant` and sets it to true, then radians are preserved throughout as a double.  It looks like `isRadiant` was introduced somewhere between Mapbox Android SDK 3.x and [4.0.0](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/4.0.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/camera/CameraPosition.Builder.html#CameraPosition.Builder(boolean)).

```
if (isRadiant) {
    this.bearing = bearing;
} else {
    // converting degrees to radiant
    this.bearing = (float) (-bearing * MathConstants.DEG2RAD);
}
```

The builder does the arithmetic lifting.  Internally, the bearing is clearly in radians, but developers input as `degrees`.

From the docs

> - @param bearing Direction that the camera is pointing in, **in degrees clockwise from north**. This value will be normalized to be within 0
>     degrees inclusive and 360 degrees exclusive.

The example from Mapbox Android SDK 4.0, explicitly sets `isRadiant(false)` —

```
                CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(32.9, -116.9))
                        .zoom(17) // Sets the zoom
                        .isRadiant(false)
                        .bearing(180) // Rotate the camera 180 degrees
                        .tilt(30) // Set the camera tilt
                        .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

                mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(position), 7000);
```

Comment: But why is the builder converting to radians at all if it is passing that value to `CameraPosition` which should take degrees?

Comment: You have the option of radians or degrees .   But internally they work in radians.  Seems reasonable to accept both, and convert to one.

Comment: Right, but my concern is that internally the builder works with radians however the camera position accepts only degrees. Therefore, lets say you set 180 degrees in the builder class, it would then be converted to pi radians which would then pass the radian value to the constructor which is expecting degrees. Or lets say you get a cameraposition value back from the mapview and its bearing is in degrees.  You pass that into the builder constructor and it assigns the Builders bearing member to the camera position's bearing. Assigning a degree value to what "should" be a radians value.

Comment: All this to say, I think there is a bug in the way this builder class interacts with the camera position class. It should either deal with degrees internally or convert to degrees before passing the value to the constructor.

Comment: I think you bring up a good point in your comment from today.  May be worth filing a defect at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues, and referring to this thread.